# Counting the amount of chars in a line of a txt file in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, text

I have a function that reads strings from a text file and stores them in a bidimensional array with a max of 1000 lines and 81 columns (80 useful characters and `\0`).

How can I introduce a detector of how many characters there are in a single line of that text file, before I insert it into the array?

Because the exercise says that the text file can only have a max of 80 characters (useful) per line but what my function does right now is that if it has more than 80 it just keeps reading the string to the next line of the array. How do I make it so that if the line in the text file has more then 79 characters before `\n` it returns an error message?

This is the function I have that reads the file right now:

```
int lerficheiro(char texto[MAXLINHAS][MAXCARPORLINHA]) 
{
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("tudomaiusculas.txt", "r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro ao abrir o ficheiro.");
        return (-1);
    }
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        for(int linha = 0; linha < MAXLINHAS; linha++)
        {
            fgets(texto[linha], MAXCARPORLINHA, fp);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    for(int linha = 0; linha < MAXLINHAS; linha++)
    {
        for(int coluna = 0; coluna < MAXCARPORLINHA; coluna++)
        {
            if(texto[linha][coluna] >= 97 && texto[linha][coluna] <= 122)
            {
                printf("O ficheiro contem letras minusculas, a terminar.");
                return (-1);
            }
        }
    }
    return (1);
}
```

Comment: OT:  regarding: `printf("Erro ao abrir o ficheiro.");`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error indication comes from a C library function, they should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  `perror()` does all this.   Suggest: `perror( "Erro ao abrir o ficheiro." );`

Comment: regarding: `while(!feof(fp))`  This does not do what you think it does.  In general, never use: `while( !feof(...))`    Suggest: eliminating the outer `while()` loop

Comment: regarding: `if(texto[linha][coluna] >= 97 && texto[linha][coluna] <= 122)`  This is nonsense as referencing a character array results in the address of the first character in the array, not the number of characters in the array.  Suggest using `strlen()` from the `string.c` header file

Comment: This code blindly ignores any errors on the stream, never checking whether even a single call to `fgets` actually succeeds. It also assumes each line read is exactly `MAXCARPORLINHA` long, including the terminator. I sincerely doubt that is warranted, nor desired.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a counter and each time it copies a character to the file to increment by 1 under the fgets, then add an if statement to print an error

```
count++
if(count>=79){
printf("too many characters");
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MAXCARPORLINHA is 82 for 80 characters plus one for newline and one for terminating zero.
Use `strchr` to test for a newline. If not found, continue reading until a newline is found and set a flag.

```
int lerficheiro(char texto[MAXLINHAS][MAXCARPORLINHA])
{
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("tudomaiusculas.txt", "r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro ao abrir o ficheiro.");
        return (-1);
    }
    int linha = 0;
    while(fgets(texto[linha], MAXCARPORLINHA, fp))
    {
        int toolong = 0;
        while ( ! strchr ( texto[linha], '\n'))//check for newline. loop if no newline
        {
            if ( ! fgets(texto[linha], MAXCARPORLINHA, fp))//read more characters
            {
                break;//found eof
            }
            toolong = 1;//set flag
        }
        if ( ! toolong)
        {
            texto[linha][strcspn ( texto[linha], "\n")] = 0;//remove newline
            linha++;//increment to next line
            if ( linhas >= MAXLINHAS)
            {
                 break;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    for(int linha = 0; linha < MAXLINHAS; linha++)
    {
        for(int coluna = 0; coluna < MAXCARPORLINHA; coluna++)
        {
            if(texto[linha][coluna] >= 'a' && texto[linha][coluna] <= 'z')
            {
                printf("O ficheiro contem letras minusculas, a terminar.");
                return (-1);
            }
        }
    }
    return (1);
}
```